# When I'm under a specific width, my divs all stack on top of each other

Tags: html, css

Struggling with CSS today. I have four boxes that have a dynamic element to them as they both flip if a user hovers over them.

I'm trying to make them a little more responsive, and when I cut the width of my screen to a specific small size they all sit on top of each other so that I can only see one of them. Ideally i'd like them to be split up into two rows, but I'm having trouble doing that.

Anybody have any ideas?

My code looks like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="threed">
        <div class="item">
          <!-- John Doe
          -->
          <div class="thumb thumb1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemback">
          <div class="item_back_text">
            <h4>John Doe</h4>
            Tattooed snackwave fingerstache, hot chicken typewriter coloring book bicycle rights bitters 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="threed">
        <div class="item">
          <!-- John Doe
          -->
          <div class="thumb thumb2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemback">
          <div class="item_back_text">
            <h4>John Doe</h4>
            PBR&B jean shorts irony art party. Typewriter glossier seitan kombucha. Art party banh mi skateboard, .
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS looks like

```
.item, .itemback{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

.thumb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.thumb1 {
    background: url(image1.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
}

.thumb2 {
    background: url(image2.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
}

.itemback{
  opacity: .7;
  position: relative;

  .item_back_text {
    color: white;
    // text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

.item{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.threed > .item{
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
  transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
  background: #808080; width: 10em; height: 10em; border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-backface-visiblity: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
  transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.threed > .itemback{
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
  transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
  background: black; width: 10em; height: 10em; border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-backface-visiblity: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
  transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.threed:hover > .item {
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
  transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
}

.threed:hover > .itemback {
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
  transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
}
```

Would anybody have any idea what i'm doing wrong with this?

Comment: Can you post HTML please?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because at the moment none none of the divs have any actual height. `.item` and `.item-back` classes have height but are positioned absolutely so they don't affect their parents' height.

They are actually being split into two rows, but to rows of height ~2px so they look on top of each other.

Add `.threed { min-height: 250px }` and you'll see it behave how you want.

Your issue mostly comes from `.thumb`. Setting a div with a background image doesn't actually give it size (unlike putting an `<img>` in a `<div>`). Either explicitly define the dimensions of `.thumb` or use an `<img>`.